# How to make a post title link as a search query?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, search, themes

What i'm trying to achieve is to make it so that when people click on the post title it would search for that specific post title on a search page.

For example, When i click on "blog post 2", it would search for that title and display results of "blog post 2" instead of going to the post page.

Is this possible?
Thanks

Edit:

Sorry for not being brief enough, i wasn't sure how to even ask this question.

This is the current code that displays the post title:

```
    <header><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></header>
```

I want to change or add a code around it so that when it's clicked it searches for whatever the post title is instead of going to the actual post.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Depending on a lot of stuff, but possible. Clarify your question.

Comment: Just echo into the href tag something like: yoursite.com/?s=blog%20post%202, in order to do that you need to convert the $post->post_name (slug of that post) into something readable for the search, that´s why i put %20 replacing the spaces.